# Microsoft Live app multiple domains

Tags: oauth, multiple-domains, microsoft-live-connect

I have a web application which runs on one server, but multiple domains (like ab.c, a-b.c, ab.d, a-b.d etc.) are pointed to this application. I would like to use other systems' (e.g. Google, Facebook, Microsoft) authentication. Google and Facebook are working fine, but it looks like Microsoft Live allows only one domain per application. Is that correct? If yes how to handle this? Does it exactly means I have to create separate application on MS developers site and I have to choose different Client ID for authentication based on user's referrer?